# How to mark the previous end of a file while following it (tail -f/less)?

Tags: logs, tail

I'm using some log files for debug, with `less` and `G` (to go to the last line/ new input).

Whenever there is an error I press `G` and see the new lines, however I would like to set a mark or some other visual aid to distinguish what I had already read and the new data written in this last error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `-W` switch with less. It temporarily highlights the first new line after a forward movement larger than one line. The highlight gets removed at the next command that causes movement. It helps to show you what you haven't read.

If you page down for example it will highlight the next line that you haven't seen yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works, but it seems to highlight the last line of a screen when the last page is not complete (you page down to the last page, but you've already sqw some of the previous lines).